# SharePoint Calendar Workflow Issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, sharepoint-calendar

Months before I arrived at this job, my current organization contracted a 3rd party to build an Out of Office calendar that essentially was going to be used as a requested time off kind of system. The user would click a tile in the calendar and add a request for time off, then the workflow would send an email to the supervisor for processing. It uses a "pending" & "approved" status system.

My supervisor says the whole workflow is unreliable/doesn't work. If we click on "IT Test", we are redirected to a "page not found" page. Furthermore, when I try to edit the workflow I get an error saying it can't be customized within the browser. I've heard before that the original user who created the workflow must be the one to edit it? Is this true? Any possible solution would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Btw, this is SharePoint Online - Classic

Comment: I've just downloaded the 32-bit SharePoint Designer. When I circle back to my SharePoint Online page, go to edit mode, click the calendar tab, and select workflow settings, it still won't let me view/edit the workflow settings? Is there any way I can gain access and modify the workflow?


I also tried going through the SharePoint Designer client itself, clicking on "Open Site", but can't seem to locate the correct SharePoint Online page... I suspect that I can only attempt to view/edit SharePoint 2013 as opposed to SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 1):

**I've heard before that the original user who created the workflow must be the one to edit it? Is this true?**

**No,** it's not true!

The required permission to edit the workflow is **Contribute** Permission level.

---

Regarding the **workflow can't be customized from the browser**

It's normal behavior, to edit the workflow you should use the same tool that has been used to design this workflow like:

- SharePoint Designer.

  - If the workflow has been created using the SharePoint designer, you can open the site and edit the workflows as you prefer.

    [image]
- The 3rd party tool like Nintix, K2 ...etc
- Visual Studio.

Comment: I've just downloaded the 32-bit SharePoint Designer. When I circle back to my SharePoint Online page, go to edit mode, click the calendar tab, and select workflow settings, it still won't let me view/edit the workflow settings? Is there any way I can gain access and modify the workflow?


I also tried going through the SharePoint Designer client itself, clicking on "Open Site", but can't seem to locate the correct SharePoint Online page... I suspect that I can only attempt to view/edit SharePoint 2013 as opposed to SharePoint Online?

Comment: don't locate the page, locate the workflows tab as I above shown. in workflows, you should find your workflow name!